# Styling Ribbon Controls

Tags: wpf, devexpress, richedit

Could anyone point me to some good documentation on how to theme or style the dev express rich edit ribbon controls.

Comment: The best way to theme any control is just use Expression Blend...and edit the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style any DevExpress controls I recommend you use the WPF Theme Editor tool. 
[image]
This is a standalone application designed to help developers create new and modify existing DevExpress WPF Themes with ease.

Related links: [The Theme Editor for WPF](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Themes/Theme-Editor.xml)

Tutorial Videos:
  [Getting Started](http://www.youtube.com/embed/Wh6iF8hg49E?autoplay=1)
  [Working with Expression Blend](http://www.youtube.com/embed/x4JeINuXTas?autoplay=1)